# How to insert a one column page within a twocolumn document?

Tags: two-column, multicol

I have a `twocolumn` layout which is rendering quite well except for the last page. The incriminated page contains a bibliography with several URLs, each one being cut on several lines.

For better readability, I would like to expand this part of the document to one column. I experimented with the `multicol` package but it's a pain when working with a lot of figures, tables, algorithms or any kind of float.

Is there any other way to achieve this result?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

switch to one column with `\onecolumn` before the last page